# In a Scrapy Demo,ImagePipeline can't be added into settings.py

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

In my Scrapy Demo , the class extends ImagesPipelines can't be add into settings.py.
this is my pipelines.py:

```
class Douyu3Pipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    IMAGES_STORE = get_project_settings().get("IMAGE_STORE")

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        print("1---------------------------1")
        image_url = item["imagelink"]
        yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_path = [x["path"] for ok, x in results if ok]
        os.rename(self.IMAGES_STORE + "/" + image_path[0],
                  self.IMAGES_STORE + "/" + item["nickname"] + ".jpg")
        item['imagePath'] = self.IMAGES_STORE + '/' + item['nickname']
        return item
```

this is my settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'douyu3'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['douyu3.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'douyu3.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'DYZB/1 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.3.0',
}
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   "douyu3.pipelines.Douyu3Pipeline": 1,
}
IMAGE_STORE = "/Users/enritami/desktop/SearchEngineer/douyu3/Images"
```

the error output is that there are none in ITEM_PIPELINES
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIyUx.png)

Comment: What are you trying to do? What happens instead? Are there any error messages? You're missing a lot of the detail that would be required for someone to help you out.

Comment: from debug ,item don't enter get_media_requests() but can enter process_item()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IMAGE_STORE in settings.py should be define as IMAGES_STORE